# incorrect output with TBB pipeline

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, tbb

I have written a C structure with different values (100 times) in text files such as **1.txt, 2.txt ... 100.txt**

---

I am using Intel TBB on Linux. I have created:

1. InputFilter (serial_in_order   MODE)
2. TransformFIlter (serial_in_order MODE)
3. OutputFilter (Serial_in_order MODE)

The InputFilter reads structure from a file and passes it to TransformFilter. 
The TrasnformFilter updates the structure values and passes it to OutputFilter. 
The OutputFilter writes the new structure on the disc.

***Basically, it is simple read and write application for a structure.***

```
class InputFilter: public tbb::filter {
public:
    InputFilter( int );
    ~InputFilter();
private:
    int total_streams;
    int count;
    struct video_process_object input_obj;
    void* operator()( void* );
};

InputFilter::InputFilter( int x )
        : filter( serial_in_order ) {
    total_streams = x;
    count = 1;
}

InputFilter::~InputFilter() {
    total_streams = 0;
}

void* InputFilter::operator()( void* ) {
    char path[50] = { };
    sprintf( path, "input//%d.txt", count );
    printf( "Path : %s\n", path );
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen( path, "r" );

    if( fp == NULL || count > total_streams ) {
        fclose( fp );
        printf( "\n*******Cannot find more data.Terminating********\n\n\n" );
        return NULL;
    }

    fscanf( fp, "%d", &input_obj.video_id );
    fscanf( fp, "%s", &input_obj.storage_url );
    fscanf( fp, "%s", &input_obj.storage_type );
    fscanf( fp, "%d", &input_obj.face_detect );
    fscanf( fp, "%d", &input_obj.face_recognise );
    fscanf( fp, "%d", &input_obj.scene_recognise );
    fscanf( fp, "%d", &input_obj.activity_recognise );
    fscanf( fp, "%d", &input_obj.speech_recognise );
    fclose( fp );

    count++;
    return &input_obj;
}

class TransformFilter: public tbb::filter {
public:
    TransformFilter();
    ~TransformFilter();
private:
    struct video_process_object input_transform;
    void* operator()( void* );
};

TransformFilter::TransformFilter()
        : filter( serial_in_order ) {
}

TransformFilter::~TransformFilter() {
}

void* TransformFilter::operator()( void *item ) {

    input_transform = *static_cast<struct video_process_object*>( item );

    input_transform.video_id += 1000;
    strcat( input_transform.storage_url, "  nabeel" );
    strcat( input_transform.storage_type, " N" );
    input_transform.face_detect += 1000;
    input_transform.face_recognise += 1000;

    return &input_transform;
}

class OutputFilter: public tbb::filter {
public:
    OutputFilter();
    ~OutputFilter();
private:
    struct video_process_object output_obj;
    void* operator()( void* );
};

OutputFilter::OutputFilter()
        : filter( serial_in_order ) {
    int status = mkdir( "output", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO );
    if( status == -1 )
        printf( "\nOutput directory already exists\n\n" );
}

OutputFilter::~OutputFilter() {
}

void* OutputFilter::operator()( void *item ) {

    output_obj = *static_cast<struct video_process_object*>( item );

    FILE *fp;

    char path[50] = { };
    sprintf( path, "output//%d.txt", output_obj.video_id - 1000 );
    printf( "Output Path : %s\t\t %d\n\n", path, output_obj.video_id );

    if( (fp = fopen( path, "w" )) == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Cannot open output file.\n" );
        return NULL;
    }

    fprintf( fp, "%d\n", output_obj.video_id );
    fprintf( fp, "%s\n", output_obj.storage_url );
    fprintf( fp, "%s\n", output_obj.storage_type );
    fprintf( fp, "%d\n", output_obj.face_detect );
    fprintf( fp, "%d\n", output_obj.face_recognise );
    fprintf( fp, "%d\n", output_obj.scene_recognise );
    fprintf( fp, "%d\n", output_obj.activity_recognise );
    fprintf( fp, "%d\n", output_obj.speech_recognise );

    fclose( fp );
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    tbb::pipeline pipeline;

    InputFilter input_filter( 100 );
    pipeline.add_filter( input_filter );

    TransformFilter transform_filter;
    pipeline.add_filter( transform_filter );

    OutputFilter output_filter;
    pipeline.add_filter( output_filter );

    tbb::tick_count t0 = tbb::tick_count::now();

    tbb::task_scheduler_init init_parallel;
    pipeline.run( 1 );
    tbb::tick_count t1 = tbb::tick_count::now();

    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine with small number of files such 5 or 10. The problem starts when I read large number of files such as 50 or 100. The problem is:

> Sometimes InputFilter reads 10.txt file and TransformFilter processes it. But immediately InputFilter reads 11.txt. OutputFIlter skips 10.txt and processes 11.txt.

How can I make sure that this will not happen?

Comment: the problems (if any) are in filter definitions. Please add them to the code. Also, you specified tokens=1, it means serial execution, is it intended? And please fix the indention (remove spaces before 'The code for main program is')

Comment: no i tried with different no of tokens. It was not working that's why I tried with one at the end . . I have attached the complete code

Comment: one more thing i realized. . I fixed my code. Now it's working fine with serial execution. Though it does not work fine with parallel execution, such as if I use token more than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a data-race, because the video_process_objects are placed inside filter structure and passed by reference between filters (which run in parallel of course). So, you have the situation when `InputFilter` starts processing the next token reading new data into its video_process_object while the first token just starts reading the data by the same address in `TransformFilter`:

```
     Token 1                ||         Token 2
input_filter.operator()     ||
transform_filter.operator() ||  input_filter.operator()
...
```

To fix it, allocate the data dynamically, e.g.:

```
struct video_process_object *input_obj_ptr = new video_process_object;
fscanf( fp, "%d", &input_obj_ptr->video_id );
...
return input_obj_ptr;
```

And deallocate it in the last filter since its return value is ignored anyway.
The slides 49-50 in [this old presentation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15499-s09/www/handouts/TBB-HPCC07.pdf) sketches the similar code.

And finally, let me challenge your choice of tbb::pipelene and serial_in_order filter type. The [TBB Reference](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/algorithms/pipeline_cls.htm) says:

> Parallel filters are preferred when practical because they permit parallel speedup. If a filter must be serial, the out of order variant is preferred when practical because it puts less contraints on processing order.

I see no reasons to put this additional 'in order' limitation since the processing and files are independent. And another quote to consider for sake of better-structured code:

> Function parallel_pipeline provides a strongly typed lambda-friendly way to build and run pipelines.

Comment: hi. .  thanks for ur comments. I have used dynamic allocation and things seem to work fine. One last thing . . In dynamic allocation, how I will deallocate the memory? Because I return the structure value from the filter

Comment: Regarding serial_in_order or serial_out_order with filters, I am just doing some experiments as ultimate goal is to use it with different application, which will use this sequence. In current example, it is not necessary u r right. I am also learning to use TBB. May be in coming days, I will jump to parallel_pipeline. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: deallocate it in the last filter since its return value is ignored anyway.

Comment: hi thanks a lot. Can u plz have a look at my question. I updated it and need little bit more guidance . . .

Comment: it deserves a separate question, please write it and put the link here, I'll look (also please remove the second question from the description here)

Comment: Did it. The new question can be found at :        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23384840/guidance-with-input-filter-for-tbb-pipeline-library